# How to remove this soql query

Tags: apex, bulkification

In my trigger i am using below code. With this code i am trying to update 2 fields if lead Owner is that particular queue or its members..

```
Group Tccqueue = [SELECT Id, name FROM Group WHERE type='Queue' and Name='TCC Counsellors' Limit 1];
List<GroupMember> queueMembers = [SELECT Group.Name, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId =: Tccqueue.Id ]; 
  for( Lead ld : Trigger.new ) {
    for (GroupMember qm :queueMembers  ) {
         if( ld.ownerid == Tccqueue.Id ) {
             ld.TCC_Lead_Status__c = ld.Status;
             ld.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = qm.Group.Name;
         } else if( ld.ownerid == qm.UserOrGroupId ) {
             User us = [SELECT Id,name FROM User where id =: qm.UserOrGroupId];
             ld.TCC_Lead_Status__c = ld.Status;
             ld.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = us.name;
         }
       }
     }
```

How can i remove the SOQL query used inside For Loop as this is very bad practice..Please suggest

Also is it possible to achieve this functionality without code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should always use collection like `Map` and `Set` to hold values which you will need later while `for-loop` iteration.
Something like that:

```
Group Tccqueue = [SELECT Id, name FROM Group WHERE type='Queue' and Name='TCC Counsellors' Limit 1];
Map<Id,GroupMember> queueMembers = new Map<Id,GroupMember>(); 

for(GroupMember gm : [SELECT Group.Name, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId =: Tccqueue.Id ])
{
    queueMembers.put(gm.UserOrGroupId,gm);
}

Map<id,Users> userfromQueue = new Map<id,User>([SELECT id FROM User WHERE Id IN:queueMembers.keyset()]);

for( Lead ld : Trigger.new ) {
    if( ld.ownerid == Tccqueue.Id ) {
        ld.TCC_Lead_Status__c = ld.Status;
        ld.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = qm.Group.Name;
    }
    else if(queueMembers.containsKey(ld.ownerid)) {   
        ld.TCC_Lead_Status__c = ld.Status;
        ld.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = userfromQueue.get(ld.ownerid).name;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: *Code is given for the idea how we can use collection. It may work or you may need to make some tweaks.*

Comment: Hi Ashwini Tahsnk for reply....but it is not working and problem i think is in line                       else if(queueMembers.containsKey(ld.ownerid)) {

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar If it is not going inside this it means that there is no group member have lead OwnerID = UserGroupID where group member belongs to `Tccqueue`.

Answer (score 4):

Add this immediately after the queueMembers query:

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
for (GroupMember qm :queueMembers) ids.add(qm.UserOrGroupId);

Map<Id, User> users = new map<Id, User>([
        SELECT Id, name
        FROM User
        where id in :ids
        ]);
```

then inside the lookup you can get the User like this:

```
User us = users.get(qm.UserOrGroupId);
```

This follows the pattern of collecting the relevant Id values then querying all the objects in one go. Map has a handy constructor that uses the Id values as the key and the SObject value as the value.

Can this be done without code - I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can take this simple approach:

> 1. Find the GroupMembers from the Group and put those Ids into a Map.
> 2. From the Map, find if lead owner Id exists and then update corresponding values

```
Map<Id, GroupMember> members = new Map<Id, GroupMember>([ SELECT Id, GroupId, UserOrGroupId
                            FROM GroupMember
                            WHERE GroupId IN (SELECT id FROM Group WHERE type='Queue' and Name='TCC Counsellors') ]);

List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
for(GroupMember member: members.values()) {
   ids.add(member.UserOrGroupId);
}


                        
for( Lead ld : Trigger.new ) 
  {
      if(ids.containsKey(ld.OwnerId))
      {
          //do your update
      }
  }
```

Comment: -1 from me for a code dump without explanation

Comment: I was editing that moment

Comment: Then you  weren't ready to post your answer.

Comment: I kind of agree with you both...I know it's a race to answer with some of these, but do try to at least get enough content together that if you don't edit, it's tolerable.

Comment: I liked the way you queries but its not correct for my problem...as keyset in your map will contain Id' of groupMember record(011....) not Group members itself (005....)

Comment: oh, I got it...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a Map before looping through trigger.new

```
Map<Id,User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>();
Set<Id> UserOrGroupIds = new Set<>();

For(GroupMember gm: queueMembers ) {
   UserOrGroupIds.add(gm.UserOrGroupId);
}

userMap.putAll([Select Id, Name from User where id In: UserOrGroupIds]);
```

And later access this in else by using userMap.get(gm.UserOrGroupId).Name;